# How to find a substring anywhere in a string

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

This should be easy, but I'm finding it difficult.

I just want to find whether a substring exists anywhere in a string. In my case, whether the name of a website exists in the title of a product.

My code is like this:

```
#FindNoCase("Amazon.com", "Google Chromecast available at Amazon")#
```

The above returns a `0` which is correct because the entire substring "Amazon.com" doesn't exist in the main string. But some of it does, namely the "Amazon" part.

How could I achieve what I'm trying to do which is just see if ANY of the substring (at least more than 2 character in length) exists in the main string?

So I need something like FindOneOf() but actually "find at least three of". It should then look at the word "Amazon" in the product title and check if at least 3 characters in the sequence of "Amazon.com" exists. When it sees that "Ama" exists, then it just needs to return a `true` value. Can it be done using the existing built-in functions somehow?

Update: Very simple solution. I used Left("amazon", 3).

Comment: What does it return? Any number other than 0 means it's a match. It should return something around 25 (the position `Amazon` starts in the string.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I typed the values incorrectly. I have updated my post to show the correct values.

Comment: You're searching for `Amazon.com` and it's not in the string.

Comment: That's correct. I guess my question should be reworded to find whether any of a substring exists in the main string. That would be FindOneOf() but that checks individual characters. So it will return 1 because the letter A exists in the first position.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of danger in false positives, like if someone was buying the Alabama state flag.

Because of store names that contain spaces, this is a little tricky (Wal Mart is often written with a space).

If your string always contains `at [store]`, you can extract the store name by finding the last at in the sentence and creating a string by chopping off everything else.

Because it looks for occurrences of `at` only as a whole word, there's no danger with store names such as `Beats Audio`, or `Sam's Meat Shop`. I can't think of any any stores with the word at in the name. While that would technically trip it up, there's much lower risk, and you can do a pre-replace on such store names.

```
<cfset mystring = "Google Chromecast available at Amazon">
<cfset SellerName = REReplaceNoCase(mystring,".*\b(?:at)\b(?!.*\b(?:at)\b)\s*","")>
<cfoutput>Seller: #Sellername#</cfoutput>
```

You can then do your comparisons much more safely.

---

Per your comment, If you know all possible patterns, you can still obtain the data if you want to (false positives can either be embarrassing or catastrophic, depending on the action). If you know the stores you're working with, you can use a regex to pull out the string like this

```
<cfset mystring = "Google Chromecast available at Amazon.co.uk">
<cfset SellerName = REReplaceNoCase(mystring,".*\b((Google|Amazon|Wal[\W]*Mart|E[\W]*bay)(\.[a-z]+)*)\b","\1")>
<cfoutput>Seller: #Sellername#</cfoutput>
```

The only part you need to update is the pipe-delimited list You might add K-Mart as `K[\W]*Mart` the `[\W]*` permits any special character or space so it covers kMart, K-Mart, k*Mart, but not Kwik-E-Mart.

---

Update #2, per more comments

```
<cfset mystring = "Google Chromecast available at Toys-R-US">
<cfset SellerNameRE = REReplace(rsProduct.sellername,"[\W]+","[\W]*","ALL")>
<cfset TheSellerName = REReplaceNoCase(mystring,".*\b((#sellernameRE#)(\.[a-z]+)*)\b","\1")>
<cfoutput>Seller: #TheSellername# (#SellerNameRE#)</cfoutput>
```

This replaces any symbols with the wildcard character so that symbols aren't required so that if something says Wal*Mart, it will still match WalMart.

You could also load a seperate column with "Regex Names" so that you're not doing this each time.

So your table would look something like

```
SellerID    SellerName    RegexName
1           Wal-Mart      Wal[\W]*Mart
2           Toys-R-US     Toys[\W]*R[\W]*US

<cfset mystring = "Google Chromecast available at Toys-R-US">
<cfset TheSellerName = REReplaceNoCase(mystring,".*\b((#rsProduct.RegexName#)(\.[a-z]+)*)\b","\1")>
<cfoutput>Seller: #TheSellername# (#SellerNameRE#)</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not always ending with "at storename". It could be along the lines of "Amazon Prime now 50% off". So we have Amazon at the front of the title instead.

Comment: @volumeone See my edit, it's still possible. Though again, false positives may occur (It will pick up the last match. In the string "Google is selling Amazon Kindle", it will pick up Amazon. Now, if you change the very first `.*` to `.*?`, it picks up Google.

Comment: this is really interesting. the SellerName and ProductTitle actually come from a cfquery recordset. So how could I implement the regex to check against the value in `rsProduct.SellerName` rather than `Google|Amazon|Wal[\W]*Mart` etc? Sorry my regex skills are very basic

Comment: @volumeone do you have specific sellers, or are there many? Ideally you would do the pipe delimited list, but, to do what you want, you could go with `<cfset TheSellerName = REReplaceNoCase(mystring,".*\b((#rsProduct.sellername#)(\.[a-z]+)*)\b","\1")>`. (I changed the variable name to TheSellerName since I see you were using that as a query column name)

Comment: There are hundreds of sellers. And more keep being added. Would there be any significant performance hit if I do this on a "master" page that lists Products in batches of 15. So it first loads 15, and then you can paginate to the next 15 and so on. I ask this because I'll have to do the regex replacement, and then run the FindNoCase() function.

Comment: @volumeone There, I updated with two methods on how I'd do this, knowing what little I know.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing this

```
#FindNoCase(left("Amazon.com", 3), "Google Chromecast available at Amazon")#
```

Yes there is potential it won't do what I need in cases where the seller name less than 3 characters long. But I think its rare enough to be ok.